# Is there any formula I'm unaware of?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$\int_{ac}^{ab} {f(x)}dx =  \int_{c}^{b } {f(ax)}dx$

Is there any definite integral formula like this? I was studying improper integrals and suddenly I found an application of that formula (though I'm not sure). I've searched through the web but nothing I found related to this.

[This is what I found on my textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3aM8.jpg)

Comment: It is one of the basic integration techniques: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Comment: The formula is obviously false, as you can see taking the constant function $f=1$ and some specific values for $a$, $b$ and $c$. A change of variable $x\to ax$ will give you the correct formula.

Comment: And you misread your textbook, which was correct.

Comment: OP says "... like this." Not exactly this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally understood. @jjagmath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula should be

$$\int_{ac}^{ab}f(x)dx=a\int_c^bf(ax)dx$$